# Does anyone know how to get the QGIS Web Client measure tool to show units in feet and miles?

Tags: qgis, convert, measurements, qgis-web-client

Does anyone know how to change the QGIS Web Client measure tool (distance and area) so that it shows feet or miles rather than meters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change some code in qgis-web-client / site / js / WebgisInit.js
you can add `unit` parameter to `OpenLayers.Control.Measure` method. you have to do this for polygon too...

```
measureControls = {
    line: new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
      OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
        persist: true,
        units:'ft',
        handlerOptions: {
          layerOptions: {styleMap: styleMapMeasureControls}
        }
      }
    )
```

> other units are ‘degrees’ (or ‘dd’), ‘m’, ‘ft’, ‘km’, ‘mi’, ‘inches’..

i hope it helps you....

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Unfortunately this doesn't work for me under Linux Mint 12.  I even went so far as to download the latest QGIS Web Client code and re-configure.  The measure distance tool still shows units in meters and kilometers rather than feet and miles.  In a perfect world, QGIS Web Client would use the same units as the coordinate system.  Or at least it should be configurable inside GlobalOptions.js.  BTW, I changed the units from 'degrees' to 'ft' inside GlobalOptions.js and still no go.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. You'd think just changing the units would do it but it doesn't. You need to set the 'displaySystem' option to switch to "American Metric/SAE", aka 'english'.

```
    measureControls = {
        line: new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
        OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
            persist: true,
            units:'ft',
            displaySystem: 'english',
            handlerOptions: {
                layerOptions: {
                    styleMap: styleMapMeasureControls
                }
            }
        }),
        polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
        OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {
            persist: true,
            units:'ft',
            displaySystem: 'english',
            handlerOptions: {
                layerOptions: {
                    styleMap: styleMapMeasureControls
                }
            }
        })
    };
```